# AI in javascript

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently developping a simple game and I'm trying to program an AI using 
javascript.

```
function AI() {
ammoTrue = 0;
ammoFalse = 0;

if (round == 1) {
  AIammunition();
}

if (AIammo == "true" && round > 1) {
  //or gun or shield
  ammoTrue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);

  if (ammoTrue == 1) {
    AIshoot();
  }
  if (ammoTrue == 2) {
    AIprotect();
  }
}

if (AIammo == "false" && round > 1) {
  //or ammo or shield
  ammoFalse = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);

  if (ammoFalse == 1) {
    AIammunition();
  }
  if (ammoFalse == 2) {
    AIprotect();
  }
}
}
```

Explanation :
In the first round, I want the function `AIammunition()` to be executed. That works.
After rounds after the first one, I want to test if `AIammo` is true or false.

If the `AIammo` is true, I want to randomly execute `AIshoot` or `AIprotect`.

If the `AIammo` is false, I want to randomly execute `AIammunition` or `AIprotect`.

I later have a reset function resetting the `AIshoot` and `AIprotect` after each round, so that there can only be one of the being true.

In the first rounds (like 1 to 3), the code seems to work, but after that, the `AIshoot` and the `AIprotect` seem to be both true, as I can read in the console (I made a very clear debug).

Here is a link to my codepen, so you can check it out for yourself : http://codepen.io/ninivert/pen/VLmjqL

Thanks.

Comment: Just a guess without digging into too much detail: the line `if (ammoFalse == 1)` is probably always true because you’re checking if `ammoFalse` is some truthy value; it doesn’t strictly have to be `1`. What happens if you exchange all the double equals for triple equals?

Comment: Also, you’re making the development process unnecessarily complicated for yourself. Why are you checking against the strings `"true"` and `"false"`? Why not use real booleans? Why are you using ‘true’ and ‘false’ in variable names? Why not use negation? The line `if (ammoFalse == 1)` should be written `if (!ammo)`.

Comment: `if (ammoFalse == 1)` actually checks if it equals the value 1, not only if it's truthy.

Comment: i'm randomly generating numbers in `ammoTrue` and `ammoFalse`, so that I can execute a function depending on the number.